# How did C99 do type generic macros without _Generic (C11)?

Tags: c, generics, types, macros, c-preprocessor

While looking at the [sqrt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt) function for `tgmath.h`,
I see that there is a type-generic macro for C99.

I know how I would implement it with [Generic selection](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic),
but `_Generic` did not exist until C11.

We have legacy projects in C89, and C99.
I would like to implement type generic functionality in a similar fashion if possible.

**How does one write type generic macros in C without Generic selection?**

Comment: A compiler and its .h files may use options not available in the C spec.  IOWs, it does not have to play by the rules, we do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How did C99 do type generic macros without _Generic (C11)?

Non-portably.

There is no general way to write a type-generic macro in pre-C11 C.

If you look at the `tgmath.h` header provided as part of glibc, for example, it doesn't use `_Generic` (since it needs to work with compilers that don't support `_Generic`). Instead, it uses a number of gcc-specific features such as `__builtin_classify_type` wrapped in some remarkable macros. A comment near the top of the file says:

```
/* This is ugly but unless gcc gets appropriate builtins we have to do        
   something like this.  Don't ask how it works.  */
```

Some of the macro definitions compare `sizeof (Val)` (where `Val` is the macro argument) vs. `sizeof (double)`. This could fail if `float`, `double`, and `long double` do not all have distinct sizes.

And the whole thing is wrapped in:

```
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (2, 7)
/* a lot of ugly macro definitions */
#else
# error "Unsupported compiler; you cannot use <tgmath.h>"
#endif
```

You could probably throw something together using `sizeof`, but it would be ugly.

Is there any chance you could compile your legacy code with a compiler that supports C11, or at least the `_Generic` feature?